# Trying to rename a computer OR execute a .bat file in Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, rename

I'm trying to write a script to rename a computer (among other things) but just can't seem to figure it out. I don't really care what method I use to change the computer as long as i can change it. I found out how to read the computer name by doing

```
String computername = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

However, that doesn't seem to offer any help in **setting** the computer name. Is there a way to set the Computer Name directly in the java console?

If not, or if anyone has better experience in this area, I also wrote a script using powershell 2.0 that renames the computer. I'm trying to figure out how to run that using

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec("file location");
```

I followed the guide [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) but when trying to run a test .bat file that should just open the command line I just get this output in the java console:

```
    C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop\opencmd.bat is found 
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>C:\Users\Stephen\workspace\UNM computer rename>cmd.exe
OUTPUT>Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
OUTPUT>Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
OUTPUT>
```

It looks like it's just spitting back the command line output into the java console, instead of just running the command and opening the cmd line.

I would really appreciate input as I'm in a crunch for time here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, JDK really does not provide pure java API that allows changing computer name. So you have to run script.

Second, if you want to run script using Runtime you have to provide correct command line. So first try to run your script manually. I believe it accepts a least one parameter (the new computer name). So run it from command prompt and see it is working. Then put it to the working directory of your java program and copy/paste the command line into the java code and see that it is working now. if you want you can read STDOUT of your script and/or get its return code. If you do not care about its output just call process.waitFor() and then get the return code.

Be careful with arguments. Windows computer name may contain unicode characters and spaces. If it contains spaces surround it with quotes. Concerning unicode just try. I hope it will not cause problems to you.

You can also use ProcessBuilder class that allows better and more portable arguments passing.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks AlexR, I have got the script to run, but I'm still trying to figure out how to run it with elevated privleges and can't find a way anywhere. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **opencmd.bat** is being executed, so assuming your PowerShell script works, is it possible you don't have [administrative privileges](https://serverfault.com/questions/11879/gaining-administrator-privileges-in-powershell)?

You can also do it elegantly using JNA, I think [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netrenamemachineindomain) would be the target.  But if you are rushed for time, don't bother.

Comment: I'm not sure what your link refers to Gnon, but you're right I need to run the script as administrator or else I won't be able to successfully change the computer name. I'm at wits end trying to figure out how to run this script as administrator, I can't find a way to run anything with elevated privileges in the CMD line, in powershell, or in java. This would be so simple with a sudo command...

Comment: Oh and because this needs to be completely automatic, I can't right click and run as admin or even prompt user for authentication, I need to be able to gain elevated privileges in the script or through the command line.

Comment: Can you use the argument -runas from the bat file?